# "In spite of there being danger signs" or "in spite of the danger signs" or "In spite of danger signs, they were swimming."

Tags: phrase-usage, adverbs, adverbial-phrases

> *Although there were danger signs,they were swimming.*

If I change this sentence into "In spite of structure":

> 1. In spite of there being danger signs, they were swimming.
> 2. In spite of the danger signs, they were swimming.
> 3. In spite of danger signs, they were swimming.

Which sentence is more natural?

Comment: In spite of = despite. "Despite the danger signs posted, they were swimming." See the definition of "despite" as a preposition. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/despite // The prepositional phrase "Despite the danger signs posted" modifies, like an adjective, the subject "they." The noun object of the preposition is "signs" which is modified by two adjectives: "danger" and a past participle "posted" (acts like an adjective).

Answer (score 3):

"In spite of danger signs", with no article, sounds oddly generic, as though the existence of some danger sign somewhere on the planet should influence them.

The other two are fine; #2 is a little shorter, and #1 is a little more formal.